In WPF, how can I hide, disable, remove a ToolBar Scrollbar?
I'm using WPF in VS 2022
I'm creating a media player and put the buttons in a Toolbar. There are a couple of things I would like to remove, but maybe it's not possible. I'm assuming the object on the right is a scrollbar and I tried to disable and hide it but it still appears.
Not sure what the object on the left is.
If I can't remove them, then I guess I'll try to push them to the window border so they are out of the way when the window is maximized.
I tried putting the buttons in a stackpanel but I ran into size problems with the images, so I'm going to stick with the tool bar.
I should add that I'm trying to follow this turorial:
https://wpf-tutorial.com/audio-video/how-to-creating-a-complete-audio-video-player/
The xaml for the ToolBar
<ToolBar Grid.Row="2"  Background="#3C5B6F" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  >
    <Button Command="ApplicationCommands.Open" >
        <Image Source="/Images/search_36.png" />
    </Button>
    <Separator />
     <Button Command="MediaCommands.Pause" >
        <Image Source="/Images/pause_36.png" />
    </Button>            
    <Button Command="MediaCommands.Play" >
        <Image Source="/Images/play_48.png" />
    </Button>   
    <Button Command="MediaCommands.Stop">
        <Image Source="/Images/stop_24.png" />
    </Button>
</ToolBar>


It's a ToggleButton to open the overflow area. You can remove it from the Toolbar's Style. Or if you don't need the functionality of ToolBar including the overflow area, a simple StackPanel will suffice.

Thanks. I thought it was a scroll bar. I'm new to all this and hadn't  heard of ToggleButton before. It looks like it can't be removed, so I went back to try and use a StackPanel again. I finally realized that the problem I was having was because the default setting for orientation is vertical. I thought it was horizontal. I'll just use that now.
